# .includes with .order does not use single query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

With this query:

```
cases = Case.includes(:arrangement)
```

I can loop through all the cases and get arrangement values without more queries being generated every time I call `case.arrangement.id`

With this query:

```
cases = Case.includes(:arrangement).order('arrangements.id asc')
```

As i loop through all the cases and get arrangement values it runs another query to load the arrangement record for that case.

How can I use `.includes` along with ordering by an arrangement column and not have a separate query run every time I call `case.arrangement.id`?

Here's how I'm looping after I run the query:

```
cases_array = []
cases.each_with_index do |caseObj, i|
  json_case = caseObj.as_json
  json_case = json_case.merge(
    :arrangement_id => caseObj.arrangement.try(:id),
    :arrangement_location => caseObj.arrangement.try(:location).try(:name),
    :arrangement_datetime => view_context.spell_date_and_time(
      caseObj.arrangement.try(:timeslot).try(:timeslot)))
  cases_array[i] = json_case
  puts json_case
end
```

Comment: Can you show how you are looping?

Comment: Does `order('arrangements.id asc')` work without referencing arrangements table as you are eager loading arrangement?

Comment: I'm not following. If i added that order clause without the `.includes(:arrangements)` it would error out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add more in your include?

```
cases = Case.includes(arrangement: [:location, :timeslot]).order('arrangements.id asc')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `arrangements`*(table name)* as `references` as well:

```
cases = Case.includes(:arrangement).order('arrangements.id asc').references(:arrangements)
```